# Unity - Resolution of the dependency failed

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, unity-container

I am getting an error while trying resolving with Unity.

```
Microsoft.Practices.Unity.ResolutionFailedException occurred
  HResult=0x80131500
  Message=Resolution of the dependency failed, type = "Dell.EMC.CPM.Core.MessageCenter.Sender.ISenderService", name = "(none)".
Exception occurred while: Calling constructor Microsoft.Practices.Unity.InterceptionExtension.PolicyInjectionBehavior(Microsoft.Practices.Unity.InterceptionExtension.CurrentInterceptionRequest interceptionRequest, Microsoft.Practices.Unity.InterceptionExtension.InjectionPolicy[] policies, Microsoft.Practices.Unity.IUnityContainer container).
Exception is: NullReferenceException - Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Inner Exception 1:
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

I am using Unity.Interception.NetCore Unity.NetCore nuget packages in my C# core console application.

Search the web and didn't find any clue why I am getting this error.
Here is my code:

My Interface:

```
public interface ISenderService
{
    [CommandSaving]
    Task<MessageResponse> SendRequest(MessageRequest req);
}
```

My derived class:

```
public class MassTransitSenderService : ISenderService
{
    ...
    public async Task<MessageResponse> SendRequest(MessageRequest req)
    {
     ...
    }
}
```

HandlerAttribute class:

```
public class CommandSavingAttribute : HandlerAttribute
{
    public string Topic               // Topic is a named parameter
    { get; set; }

    public override ICallHandler CreateHandler(IUnityContainer container)
    {
        return new CommandSavingCallHandler();
    }

}
```

ICallHandler class:

```
    public class CommandSavingCallHandler : ICallHandler
    {

        public IMethodReturn Invoke(IMethodInvocation input, GetNextHandlerDelegate getNext)
        {
            Logger.Log("Log CommandSavingCallHandler");
        }
```

and the code of the resolving:

```
    var container = new UnityContainer();

    container.RegisterType<ISenderService, MassTransitSenderService>(
        new InterceptionBehavior<PolicyInjectionBehavior>(),
        new Interceptor<InterfaceInterceptor>());

    container.AddNewExtension<Interception>();

    container.Configure<Interception>().SetInterceptorFor<ISenderService>(
        new InterfaceInterceptor());
    var massTransitsenderService = container.Resolve<ISenderService>();
```

When I delete the [CommandSaving] that located in my interface above the function I want to Intercepate, I get not error.

Any ideas what is the problem?

Comment: how does your Startup look like? do you add any dependency's? At first glance it looks like it's missing a dependency

Comment: @TheRuler My Startup is a console application that runs the resolving code I added at the bottom, nothing special

Comment: @TheRuler When I delete the [CommandSaving] that located in my interface above the function I want to Intercepate, I get not error.